# ¿Cómo renderizar imágenes mediante JSON en React?

Tags: json, reactjs

Hace poco empecé un proyecto en *React* con `create-react-app` y tras crear algunos componentes quise optimizar mi código con un *JSON* que contuviera los elementos necesarios que lograran renderizar de una manera más fácil mi proyecto, sin necesidad de colocarlos uno por uno o *hardcodearlos*.

Pero en mi *JSON* las imágenes contenidas no se logran renderizar en el navegador a pesar de que el resto de la información sí, supongo que me hace falta importar las imágenes de alguna manera.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

- **`App.js`**

  ```
      import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import './App.css';
      import Playlist from "./components/playlist";
      import data from "./api.json";

      //import './images/covers/responsive.jpg';

      class App extends Component {
      render() {
          return (
          <div>
              <Playlist data={data}/>
          </div>
          );
      }
      }

      export default App;
  ```
- **`playlist.js`**

  ```
  import React from 'react';
  import Media from './media.js';
  import './playlist.css';

  function Playlist (props) {
      const playlist = props.data.categories[0].playlist
      console.log(props.data);
      return(
          <div className="Playlist">
              {
              playlist.map((item) => {
              return <Media {...item} key={item.id}/>
              })
              }
          </div>
      )
  }

  export default Playlist;
  ```
- **`media.js`**

  ```
      import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
      import './media.css';
      import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

      class Media extends PureComponent {
          handleClick = (event) => {
              console.log(this.props.title)
          }
          render() {
              return(
                  <div className="Media" onClick = {this.handleClick}>
                      <div className="Media-cover">
                          <img className="Media-cover" src={this.props.cover} alt="cover" width={260} height={160}/>
                          <h3 className="Media-title">{this.props.title}</h3>
                          <p className="Media-author">{this.props.author}</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              )
          }
      }

      //VALIDATORS
      Media.propTypes = {
          cover: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
          title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
          author: PropTypes.string,
      }

      export default Media;
  ```

Comment: {
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Lo mejor de la semana",
      "title": "Destacados",
      "playlist": [
        {
          "title": "¿Qué es responsive Design?",
          "author": "Olivolacroix",
          "type": "video",
          "cover": "./images/covers/responsive.jpg",
          "src": "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4",
          "id": 1
        },

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo usando `require('./path/to/image')`

En tu caso quedaría de esta manera:

```
class Media extends PureComponent {
  handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(this.props.title)
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="Media" onClick = {this.handleClick}>
        <div className="Media-cover">
          <img className="Media-cover" src={require(`${this.props.cover}`)} alt="cover" width={260} height={160}/>
          <h3 className="Media-title">{this.props.title}</h3>
          <p className="Media-author">{this.props.author}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Por alguna razón el require debe ser de esta forma:

```
require(`${this.props.cover}`)
```

De otra forma dará un error diciendo que el módulo no existe

Answer (score 0):

falto colocar tu json para poder ver el codigo de forma correcta.

```
src={`${this.props.cover}`}
```

de momento esto deberia funcionar eso claro si no tienes un error en la ruta de tu archivo.